# How To Center Adsense Code in Mobile Device

Tags: html, css

My code:

```
<div style="style="display:block; float: left; margin: 0px 50px 0px px;>
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- Paragraph Ad 3rd - Responsive -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxx"
     data-ad-slot="xxxxx"
     data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>   
</div>
```

Google Adsense is perfectly centered in desktop, even when i resize the device: 
[image]

But, When i test it on real mobile device, it is not centered: 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
<div align="center" style="display:block; float: left; margin: 0px 50px 0px px;">
```

if that does not work then try this in the style attribute

```
text-align: center;
```

Comment: It was cache...I even try to reload without cache, but it did not work. It worked after deleting all the history with cache.

Comment: Good for you !!

Answer (score 0):

you can put center tags around your Adsense code. Something like this:

```
<center>
<div style="style="display:block; float: left; margin: 0px 50px 0px px;>
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- Paragraph Ad 3rd - Responsive -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxx"
     data-ad-slot="xxxxx"
     data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>   
</div>
</center>
```

Hope this helps man.
Cheers.

Comment: It is not supported in HTML5, i don't know, why it matter. But i am advised not to use center tags.

Comment: Does it not even work. Like is it a warning or there is no response from the page.